# Unable to access tm.corpus.Reuter21578

Tags: r, tm

i am working on a project that has to connect tweets with news. any ideas how that is possible? I am trying to access tm.corpus.Reuters21578 package in R. but when i execute the following code i get an error.

```
library(tm)
corpus <- Corpus(DirSource("Data/reuters"), list(reader = readReut21578XML))
```

Error received:
     Error in DirSource("Data/reuters") : empty directory

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
corpus <- Corpus(DirSource(reut21578),
    readerControl = list(reader = readReut21578XML))
```